# How to use GROUP BY and ORDER BY together in LARAVEL 5.6

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, group-by, eloquent

I'm using LARAVEL 5.6

I'm using Eloquent. I want to use `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` together, I've some experiences that tell me it's not as easy as it looks like, even in puer `mysql` query ;).
I've read similar questions too, But I'm still confused!

I have 2 Models (tables) called `Currency` (database table: `currencies`) and `CurrencyExchangeRate` (database table: `currency_exchange_rates`) with this informations:

```
Schema::create('currencies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title', 200)->nullable();
            $table->string('symbol', 20)->nullable();
            $table->text('icon')->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('visible')->defualt(0);
            $table->tinyInteger('order')->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('created_at');
            $table->bigInteger('updated_at');
        });
```

And

```
Schema::create('currency_exchange_rates', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('currency_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('currency_id')->references('id')->on('currencies')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->bigInteger("sell")->nullable();
    $table->bigInteger("buy")->nullable();
    $table->string('date', 20);
    $table->bigInteger('created_at');
    $table->bigInteger('updated_at');
});
```

And these are my Models:

```
class Currency extends Model
{
    /**
     * The storage format of the model's date columns.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $dateFormat = 'U';
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'symbol', 'icon', 'visible', 'order'];

    public function exchangeRate()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CurrencyExchangeRate');
    }

    public function getIconAttribute($value)
    {
        return json_decode($value);
    }
}
```

And

```
class Currency extends Model
{
    /**
     * The storage format of the model's date columns.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $dateFormat = 'U';
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'symbol', 'icon', 'visible', 'order'];

    public function exchangeRate()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CurrencyExchangeRate');
    }

    public function getIconAttribute($value)
    {
        return json_decode($value);
    }
}
```

As you see every Currency can have many currency exchange rates, I want to show user's currency exchange rates for a Currency in the last 10 days!
there are different rates for a currency in one day, I want the last rate entered in a day! for example:

```
id | currency_id | sell | buy |     date   |  created_at | updated_at
---+-------------+------+-----+------------+-------------+------------
 1 |   1         |  10  |  12 | 2018-04-05 |    1        |    1
 2 |   1         |  11  |  13 | 2018-04-05 |    2        |    2
 3 |   1         |  15  |  20 | 2018-04-05 |    3        |    3
```

As you see there are 4 rates for `currency_id = 1` in `date = 2018-04-05`, which in my report I need the latest one (created_at = 3 | sell = 15  | buy = 20)

So if I want to have a more real example my table will be like:

```
id | currency_id | sell | buy |     date   |  created_at | updated_at
---+-------------+------+-----+------------+-------------+------------
 1 |   1         |  10  |  12 | 2018-04-05 |    1        |    1
 2 |   1         |  11  |  13 | 2018-04-05 |    2        |    2
 3 |   1         |  15  |  20 | 2018-04-05 |    3        |    3
 4 |   1         |  20  |  22 | 2018-04-06 |    4        |    4
 5 |   1         |  21  |  23 | 2018-04-06 |    5        |    5

 6 |   2         |  40  |  50 | 2018-04-05 |    1        |    1
 7 |   2         |  60  |  70 | 2018-04-05 |    2        |    2
 8 |   2         |  80  |  90 | 2018-04-06 |    4        |    4
 9 |   2         |  95  |  85 | 2018-04-06 |    5        |    5
```

I want to have an array like this:

```
$currencies = [
            'currency_id ' => 1,
            'title' => 'Dollar',
            'currency_exchange_rates' => [
                '2018-04-05' => [
                    'sell' => 15,
                    'buy' => 20,
                    'created_at' => 3, // the latest rate entered in 2018-04-06 for 'currency_id ' => 1 
                ] ,
                '2018-04-06' => [
                    'sell' => 21,
                    'buy' => 23,
                    'created_at' => 5, // the latest rate entered in 2018-04-06  for 'currency_id ' => 1 
                ]
            ] ,
            'currency_id ' => 2,
            'title' => 'Euro',
            'currency_exchange_rates' => [
                '2018-04-05' => [
                    'sell' => 60,
                    'buy' => 70,
                    'created_at' => 2, // the latest rate entered in 2018-04-05 for 'currency_id ' => 2
                ] ,
                '2018-04-06' => [
                    'sell' => 95 ,
                    'buy' => 85,
                    'created_at' => 5, // the latest rate entered in 2018-04-06 for 'currency_id ' => 2 
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

I've used this code to get currency exchange rates for every currency by it's `id`:

```
$days = 10 ;
$currencies = Currency::findOrFail($currency_id)
    ->with(
    [
        'exchangeRate' => function ($q) use ($days) {
            $q->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->where('created_at', ">", strtotime('-' . $days . ' days', time()))
                ->groupBy('date')
                ->get();
        }
    ]
)->get();
```

But `ORDER BY` is not working and I will receive just first rates.

**UPDATE**

I want to get the latest rate for each **day** of the last 10 days, For example, if the admin has entered 4 rates for `USD` on `2018-04-05`, I want to get the latest one! (*I've entered just `sell` rate to simplify my example*)

```
USD = [
     2018-04-01 => 10 (the latest rate has been entered for USD on 2018-04-01 is 10),
     2018-04-02 => 13 (the latest rate has been entered for USD on 2018-04-02 is 13),
     2018-04-03 => 15 (the latest rate has been entered for USD on 2018-04-03 is 15),
     2018-04-04 => 18 (the latest rate has been entered for USD on 2018-04-04 is 18),
     2018-04-05 => 12 (the latest rate has been entered for USD on 2018-04-05 is 12),
     ...
],

EUR  = [
     2018-04-01 => 10 (the latest rate has been entered for EUR on 2018-04-01 is 10),
     2018-04-02 => 13 (the latest rate has been entered for EUR on 2018-04-02 is 13),
     2018-04-03 => 15 (the latest rate has been entered for EUR on 2018-04-03 is 15),
     2018-04-04 => 18 (the latest rate has been entered for EUR on 2018-04-04 is 18),
     2018-04-05 => 12 (the latest rate has been entered for EUR on 2018-04-05 is 12),
     ...
],
```

Comment: If you know the pure sql you can run a raw query https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#running-queries

Comment: I've some problems in  pure sql too

Comment: I am trying to follow your flow, and I just have a few questions for clarity. You have multiple currencies, CAD, USD EUR etc.... you want to get latest rate for each of the last 10 days?

Comment: @Dustin I want to get the latest rate for each **day** of the last 10 days, please see the question's update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery join:

```php
$days = 10 ;
$currencies = Currency::with(
    [
        'exchangeRate' => function ($q) use ($days) {
            $latest = CurrencyExchangeRate::select('currency_id', 'date')
                ->selectRaw('MAX(created_at) created_at')
                ->groupBy('currency_id', 'date');
            $q->joinSub($latest, 'latest', function($join) {
                $join->on('currency_exchange_rates.currency_id', 'latest.currency_id')
                    ->on('currency_exchange_rates.date', 'latest.date')
                    ->on('currency_exchange_rates.created_at', 'latest.created_at');
            })->where('currency_exchange_rates.created_at', ">", strtotime('-' . $days . ' days', time()));
        }
    ]
)->get();
```

This executes the following query:

```php
select *
from `currency_exchange_rates`
inner join (
  select `currency_id`, `date`, MAX(created_at) created_at
  from `currency_exchange_rates`
  group by `currency_id`, `date`
) as `latest`
on `currency_exchange_rates`.`currency_id` = `latest`.`currency_id`
  and `currency_exchange_rates`.`date` = `latest`.`date`
  and `currency_exchange_rates`.`created_at` = `latest`.`created_at`
where `currency_exchange_rates`.`currency_id` in (?, ...)
  and `currency_exchange_rates`.`created_at` > ?
```

Comment: It returns "exchange_rate" => []

Comment: Please create a https://www.db-fiddle.com with sample data I can use to reproduce this.

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake! it seems to work great :) Would you please update your answer and write SQL code too?

Comment: I added the SQL.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is great! but I have an idea too, I can use $currencies = Currency::findOrFail($currency_id)
    ->with(
    [
        'exchangeRate' => function ($q) use ($days) {
            $q->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->where('created_at', ">", strtotime('-' . $days . ' days', time()))
                ->get();
        }
    ]
)->get(); and then proccess the latest items in php in loop (like foreach), Do you thinck which way has the better performance?

Comment: I would say it depends on the amount of data. How many exchange rates do you have per currency and date?

Comment: I have about 10 currencies and  About 4 exchange rates  per currency in 1 day

Comment: Then you won't notice any differences in performance. Choose the code that is shorter/easier to understand.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Currency::findOrFail($currency_id)
    ->with(
    [
        'exchangeRate' => function ($q) use ($days) {
            $q->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->first();
        }
    ]
)->get();
```

Its the only way I suppose

Comment: This code just returns first exchange rate for a currency, not  exchange rate per day