# How to convert this SQL Query into Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have this SQL which will return all the jobs with converted currency rates and it works perfectly, but as we are using API Resources we have to use Eloquent model in order to get the response data like we've configured.

```
  select * from (
        select 
        jr.id,
        title,description,
        FORMAT(jr.amount,2) as base_amount,
        c.symbol as base_currency,
        FORMAT(IFNULL(jr.amount * currency_rate.rate,jr.amount),2) as amount,
        jr.created_at,
        user_id,type,country_id,city_id,
        delivery_hours,deleted_at
        from job_requests as jr
        left join currencies as c on c.id = jr.currency_id
        left join currency_rates as currency_rate on ((currency_rate.from_currency = c.symbol AND currency_rate.to_currency = "QAR"))
    ) as job_requests order by amount desc ;
```

I was able to write this

```
$jobRequests = JobRequest::from('job_requests')->select("job_requests.id", "title", "description", DB::raw("format(job_requests.amount, 2) as base_amount"), "c.symbol as base_currency", DB::raw("format(ifnull(job_requests.amount * currency_rate.rate, job_requests.amount),2) as amount"), "job_requests.created_at", "user_id", "type", "country_id", "city_id", "delivery_hours", "deleted_at")
    ->leftJoin("currencies as c", function($join){
        $join->on("c.id", "=", "job_requests.currency_id");
    })
    ->leftJoin("currency_rates as currency_rate", function($join){
        $join->on('currency_rate.from_currency','=','c.symbol');
        $join->where('currency_rate.to_currency', 'TRY');
        #$join->on('currency_rate.to_currency', '=', DB::raw("c.symbol"));
    })
```

But I don't know how to put all this inside another JobRequest model so that I can do all sorts of ordering having clauses.

Comment: what is `JobRequest`? if it is an Eloquent model, it already has an associated table, thus `from()` is not needed. Also the `leftJoin()`s are usually implemented as relationship functions. You now could just as well have used a simple `DB::table('job_requests')->select()...` (although that doesnt hydrate to an Eloquent model but a plain php object)

Comment: It is an eloquent table.

I can't use DB:: cause if I do that I won't be able to use things like $job->user->resumes etc

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/53023796/10602851

Answer (score 0):

With properly implemented [eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships), you're able to do `$jobRequests[0]->currency->currencyRate`:

```php
class JobRequest extends Model
{
    public function currency()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Currency::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class Currency extends Model
{
    public function currency_rate()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsTo(CurrencyRate::class, 'from_currency', 'symbol')
            ->where('currency_rate.to_currency', 'TRY');
    }
}
```

Comment: We've to do a lot of conversions within the query itself. that is the problem when working like this. I've implemented most things like this in our project except for this one!. Is there anyway we could write that as a subquery like I've mentioned in my post?

Comment: In your post there is no subquery. There are just joins. What kind of conversions do you need to do that can't be done?

Comment: Please see the caluclations. We've to convert all the Job Amount(Example 10000 records) into the user specified currency and then have to filter them, sort them using the new exchange rate.

Comment: I still can't see your problem, sorry. You might have to do some conversions with [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) while others can be done by using `DB::raw()`

Comment: The conversions have to be done before returning the data. I mean with in the MySQL itself. That's what I'm trying to achieve.
All i need now is to put that eloquent query into another eloquent query but I don't know how

Comment: Please see this approach @shaedrich 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53023796/10602851

Comment: Accessors are excuted before data is returned to the client or how do you define "returned"?